# Extract multiple links from one Google Sheet cell and then paste them in a Google Doc as hyperlinks using Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-docs

I would like to do the following with Google Apps Script:

1. Search an specific cell in Google Sheets with multiple URL's
2. Split the URL's and get them as separate links in order to avoid using the split function in sheets (watch the [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0CU6Q.png)
3. Attach each URL into a Google Doc by using tags

I've done this before, but I'm only able to obtain the URL's in one array and not separated (watch [image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3kvDx.png) and [image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WhXnS.png))

```
for (var i=0; i<row[rownumber].length; i++){
  if (row[rownumber].includes(",")) 
  img=row[rownumber].split(",");
  body.replaceText('{{TagName}}',img);
}
```

Here you have the example in Google Sheets in order to apply the mentioned steps ([link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1YosQwoFMbqoljRGdZddoLQgrj-gOYVYtOtm424bdSwk/edit?usp=sharing)). Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### You can refer to this sample code:

```
  var doc = DocumentApp.openById('YourDocId');   
  var body = doc.getBody();

  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var rowValues = sheet.getRange(1,1,sheet.getLastRow(),1).getValues().flat();

  //Combine all row values into a single url array
  var urls = [];
  rowValues.forEach(row => {

    if(row.includes(",")){
      var tmp = row.split(",");
      urls = urls.concat(tmp);
    }
  });

  Logger.log(urls);
  Logger.log(urls.length);
  
  if(urls.length > 0){
    var tag = "{{TagName}}";
    var newLine = "\n\n";

    var element = body.findText(tag);
    if(element){ // if found a match
        var start = element.getStartOffset();
        var text = element.getElement().asText();
        //remove tag in the docs
        text.deleteText(start,start+tag.length-1);

        //Add url
        urls.forEach(url => {
          url = url.trim(); //remove whitespaces on both ends of the url string
          Logger.log("START: "+start);
          Logger.log(url);
          Logger.log("URL LENGTH: "+url.length);
          text.appendText(url).setLinkUrl(start, start+url.length-1, url);
          text.appendText(newLine);
          start = start + url.length + newLine.length;
          Logger.log(text.getText());
          Logger.log("*****");
        });
        doc.saveAndClose();
    }
  }
```

> **Note:**
> You can remove the logs if you felt like you don't need them. I just used them to debug the code.

### What it does?

1. Get the `url` links from column A starting row 1 up to the last available row.
2. Parse each row. Split the url string into individual urls' then concatenate it to `urls` array.
3. Find your tag to be replaced in the document's body using [Body.findText(searchPattern)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/body#findtextsearchpattern)
4. Get the start offset of the matched text using [RangeElement.getStartOffset()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/range-element#getstartoffset)
5. Get the element that corresponds to the RangeElement using [RangeElement.getElement()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/range-element#getelement)
6. Get the element as text using [Element.asText()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/element#astext)
7. Delete the tag string in your document using [Text.deleteText(startOffset, endOffsetInclusive)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/text#deletetextstartoffset,-endoffsetinclusive)
8. Loop each url in the array.Take note to remove whitespaces in the current `url` string. Add the url text using [Text.appendText(text)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/text#appendtexttext). Once the url text was appended, include it's url link using [Text.setLinkUrl(startOffset, endOffsetInclusive, url)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/text#setlinkurlstartoffset,-endoffsetinclusive,-url). Add a new line using `Text.appendText(text)` then adjust the `start` offset based on the url length and the new line length. (Repeat until all the url links were added in the document)

### Output:

[image]

### (UPDATE:)

If you want to give a different name in your hyperlink, you can replace the appended text and modify the offsets in the `setLinkUrl()`

**Sample Code Changes:**

```
        //Add url
        urls.forEach((url, index) => {
          url = url.trim(); //remove whitespaces on both ends of the url string
          var name = "Image"+(index+1);
          Logger.log("START: "+start);
          Logger.log(url);
          Logger.log("URL LENGTH: "+url.length);
          Logger.log("NAME LENGTH: "+name.length);
          text.appendText(name).setLinkUrl(start, start+name.length-1, url);
          text.appendText(newLine);
          start = start + name.length + newLine.length;
          Logger.log(text.getText());
          Logger.log("*****");
        });
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: Please let me know if you encountered some issues so I could fix/update the answer

Comment: Thanks for your support here and the sample code works great. I would like to know how to do the same in case I have more than one row with multiple URL's in the same cell (I've updated the Google Sheet for you to check it). Hope it helps and thanks again!

Comment: Hi. I updated the answer. Please let me know if you encountered some issues

Comment: And by the way, If we answered your question, please click the accept button.  By doing so, other people in the community, who may have the same concern as you, will know that theirs can be resolved. If the accept button is unavailable to you, feel free to tell me. [How to accept answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235)

Comment: Thanks again for your help Ron! I've accepted your answer and it's working fine. Regards

Comment: Another question Ron, is it possible to substitute each URL with a personalized hyperlink? Instead of the full URL get something in the format of Image[number] like this: Image1, Image2, Image3, etc. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks again Ron!